# Display remote user retrieved from auth_request in access logs in Nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I have the following configuration in nginx:

```
    location /api/ {
        auth_request /auth/request/;

        auth_request_set $user $upstream_http_remote_user;
        proxy_set_header Remote-User $user;
      

        proxy_pass http://...;
    }
```

I am setting the `Remote-User` field, so I would expect that in the access log, the value would appear, but it's only `-` that appear, indicating the value does not exist. In the server proxied there, I can access the header `Remote-User`, so I know that the value is well set, but can't manage to display it in the access logs.

I suppose the access log are generated before the auth request maybe.

Is there a way to get the `Remote-User` inside the access logs with this kind of configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in you nginx.conf you should have something like

> log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local]
> "$request" '
> '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
> '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

replace `$remote_user` by your `$user` variable